# Differences between Static Factors, Dynamic factors and Exploratory factor analysis in Time Series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, econometrics, factor-analysis, vector-autoregression

I came across many types of factor analysis techniques in the context of time series data. I am not sure whether exploratory factor analysis refers to the same static factor analysis methodology.

1. If I use **exploratory factor analysis** and use rotated factors as **predictors to forecast GDP**, what is that analysis called?
2. If I take **lagged terms of the factors** obtained through **exploratory factor analysis** and build a **VAR model**, can I call it *a dynamic factor model*?

My target is to evaluate the forecast accuracy between static and dynamic factors. How can I achieve my target.

Comment: How is the [tag:large-data] tag relevant here? Do your time series have one million observations or so?

Comment: @RichardHardy sorry, I meant large-data since factor models are used for large-data sets. In my case, I have around 30 variables.

Comment: No need to be sorry :) This is what the [tag:high-dimensional] tag is used for. Whether 30 is high enough to count as high-dimensional may depend on the context.